# Windows console signal handling for subprocess c++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, signals, windows-console

Suppose we have small program, written in C++, which looks like below.
This program itself **intentionally** does NOT perform signal handling via WinAPI call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` - it's important part of question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  while(true) {
    int status = system("EXTERNAL COMMAND");
    printf("RESULT STATUS = %d\n", status);
  }
}
```

When `Ctrl+C` key combination have been pressed in terminal, program above have quite different behavior depend on which `"EXTERNAL COMMAND"` had been invoked

1) If external command is `pause`, program will stand in infinite loop, invoking `pause` command step by step, and will print `"RESULT STATUS = 0" many times`, while not terminated forced via process kill.
2) If external command in `choice`, program will terminate immediately after `Ctrl+C` pressure. It will not print anything and does not return from `system` call.
3) If external command is `set /P VAR=`, program has much interesting behavior. When `Ctrl+C` pressed, program prints `"RESULT STATUS = 1" and continue working until first async call is performed.

First and second case can be explained in following manner. Terminal windows is proxt between user input and target program, so when user presses `Ctrl+C`, terminal window perform dispatch signal itself to target process.
So some subprocesses can take manually terminal handler via `hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` and perform own signal handling. Another subprocess does not do this, so signal passed into parent process and terminate it.

But third case causes big question. If child process intercepts `SIGINT`, why parent process perform terminating after first async call. If not, why it does not terminate immediately and why and how it prints `"RESULT STATUS = 1" and continue working.

Thanks

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! Key for answer is `create a new thread in each attached process` - in this case it's clear how process termination performs in async manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Unix signals in Windows, at least not from the kernel. That said, Windows and the Windows API are fundamentally based on the C programming language, which, having been developed in tandem with Unix, does require [six signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling). The C runtime in Windows emulates `SIGABRT` and `SIGTERM` within process (e.g. for use with C `raise`). For `SIGSEGV`, `SIGILL`, and `SIGFPE` it uses an OS exception handler. In a console application, standard`SIGINT` and non-standard `SIGBREAK` are associated with the C runtime's console control handler, which is usually the first handler registered via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. `CTRL_C_EVENT` is mapped to the `SIGINT` signal handler, and all others (`CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`) are mapped to the `SIGBREAK` handler.

Console control events are sent by the console host (conhost.exe), which implements this by having the session server (csrss.exe) create a thread in a client process. This thread begins at the undocumented `CtrlRoutine` function in kernelbase.dll, which walks the registered control handlers until one of them handles the event by returning true. If none of them handles the event, the default handler calls `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)`. Note that `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE)` sets a flag that makes `CtrlRoutine` ignore `CTRL_C_EVENT`, and this flag is inherited by child processes and enabled by default when a process is created with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. Also, for `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, the session server gives each process 5 seconds to handle the event and exit on its own, else it terminates the process forcefully.

To understand what's happening with CMD's internal `PAUSE` command, see [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), and, in particular, `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`. `PAUSE` calls C `_getch`, which temporarily sets the console input mode to 0. With the processed-input mode disabled, Ctrl+C is simply read as "\x03" instead of generating a `CTRL_C_EVENT`.