# Is it possible to detect when an user closes the console in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I would like to know if it is possible to detect when a user closes the console and then execute a function that frees the memory allocated by previous malloc calls.

I know that the main OS like Windows/Linux/MacOS are supposed to free this memory when the console closes, but I think it is better to make a program to rely on the OS as few as possible.

Comment: This is going to be OS-specific, and isn't part of the C standard.

Comment: In unix, when the terminal is closed, the process is sent SIGHUP. This kills your process by default, though you could hook it (and other signals such as SIGINT and SIGTERM) to perform some cleanup. Freeing up memory is not needed, though. The OS automatically frees all memory associated with processes that exit (incl killed).

Comment: @TomKarzes I see, so the program should either rely on the OS or use tools provided by the OS (if there are some).  Then in this case the OS is more to blame for bad memory management than the program lol.

Comment: There is no bad memory management. Your program _got_ all its memory from the OS, and the OS cleans it up. That is good memory management.

Comment: @Wheatley You just need to make sure the process exits when the console closes.  When the process exits, all memory will be freed.  You just need to make sure it doesn't continue running in background.

Answer (score 2):

Re:

> it is possible to detect when a user closes the console and then
> execute a function that frees the memory allocated by previous malloc
> calls?

---

Yes, it's possible to catch the signal.

On POSIX-compliant¹ systems, the process is sent `SIGHUP`.

Macro: `int SIGHUP`

> The SIGHUP (“hang-up”) signal is used to report that
> the user’s terminal is disconnected, perhaps because a network or
> telephone connection was broken. For more information about this, see
> Control Modes.
>
> This signal is also used to report the termination of the controlling
> process on a terminal to jobs associated with that session; this
> termination effectively disconnects all processes in the session from
> the controlling terminal.

The OS will automatically `free()` the memory when the process exits. But you can use `signal()`/`sigaction()`² to change the default handling and free up resources.

> The sigaction() system call is used to change the action taken by
> a process on receipt of a specific signal.

NB that `signal()`'s behaviour varies across UNIX systems and is not portable. Avoid it's use.

The only portable use of `signal()` is to change the disposition to `SIG_IGN`/`SIG_IGN`.

Also note that neither the C standard, nor the POSIX standard specifies `free()` to be async-signal-safe, i.e. it is not safe to call it in a signal handler.

[1] — For Windows, see: [Windows console signal handling for subprocess c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54362699/20017547)

[2] — `sigaction()` is defined in the POSIX standard, not in the C standard.